# Get the product with highest sales

Tags: sql, select

I need a query to return the products that have been sold most often.

I have two tables to work with.

Product

```
 IDPRO(PK) DESCRIP                   STOCK     PRICE

   4000     PIZZA                      7       2000
   4001     HAMBURGUESA                8       800
   4002     PAELLA                     1       1000
   4003     CORDERO                    5       3000
   4004     COMIDA CHINA               9       500
   4005     ALBONDIGAS                 9       500
```

Details

```
 IDPRO(FK)   Amount

   4002          2
   4003          1
   4004          1
   4002          3
   4002          1
   4003        100
   4004         50
   4004          3
   4005         10
```

The result would be something like this

```
CORDERO
```

Since it is the product with the highest amount of sold units.

Comment: What is `CANTIDAD` column?

Comment: How do we know the number of sold items?

Comment: Looks like a homework to me, did you try anything so far?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Amount on Details Table its what youre looking for guys, sorry, my fault

Comment: Also: [edit] your question and add the expected output based on your sample data.

Comment: Ye its a homework, i already tried use JOIN but cannot figure out how get a count on details table idart with amount without using it on select statement

Comment: Next time try to figure it yourself, you will learn more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the total quantity you could use sum and group by  on the joined  tables

```
select t1.IDPRO, t1.DESCRIP, sum(t2.Amount) total 
FROM Product t1
INNER JOIN DETAILS t2 on t2.IDART = t1.IDPRO
GROUP BY  t1.IDPRO, t1.DESCRIP
ORDER BY total desc
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the sum of `CANTIDAD` column for each product and select top 1 row and join to table 1.

**Query**

```
select top 1 t1.IDPRO, t1.DESCRIP, t2.total 
from Product t1 
join (
    select IDART, sum(Amount) as total
    from Details
    group by IDART
)t2
on t1.IDPRO = t2.IDART
order by t2.total desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try somethink like this for top 1:

```
WITH MAIN AS(
SELECT main.IDPRO, main.DESCRIP, main.CANTIDAD from Details det
LEFT JOIN Product main ON main.IDPRO=det.IDART)

SELECT TOP 1 * from MAIN
```